# Better way to write a newbie's Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting out with Rails (as a complete newbie to coding) and, while I'v got this code to work, I know it will make experienced coders cringe. Please help me rewrite this better. Specifically, so that the first image becomes part of the link

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr id="topbar"><th width="60%">Name</th> 
    <th width="10%">Size</th>
    <th width="20%">Modified</th>
    <th width="5%"></th>
    <th width="5%"></th></tr>
<% @folders.each do |folder| %>
    <tr>
     <td width="60%"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/folder.gif"> <%= link_to folder.name, browse_path(folder) %></td>
     <td width="10%">-</td>
     <td width="20%">-</td>     
     <td width="5%"><%= link_to image_tag("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/page_edit.gif"), rename_folder_path(folder) %></td> 
     <td width="5%"><%= link_to image_tag("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/action_stop.gif"), folder, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete the folder and all of its contents?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The title of your post should be a summary of your question rather than how you feel about it. There's an edit link below your question that you can use to pick a more appropriate title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use raw helper.

```
<td width="60%">
  <%= link_to raw("#{image_tag('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/folder.gif')} #{folder.name}"), browse_path(folder) %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to " <td width=\"60%\"><img src=\"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/folder.gif\">#{link_to folder.name, browse_path(folder)}</td><td width=\"10%\">-</td><td width=\"20%\">-</td>" %>
```

Untested, but I'd imagine something similar should work.

Comment: For evaluate html into the link_to, use "raw" => <%= link_to raw(" "), path %>

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's block syntax to pass the image and name as a block by using do and end and passing the path as an argument for link_to.

```
<td width="60%">
  <%= link_to browse_path(folder) do %>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/folder.gif">
    <%= folder.name %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```